# Redirect user if not logged-in in Kentico

Tags: authentication, logout, kentico

I am very new to Kentico CMS and started implementing the basics.

I have Login button webpart which redirect me to page say `'Welcome.aspx'`.

Now, what I am struggling with is if directly open '`Welcome.aspx'` without login, 
it should redirect to another page. Can anyone please help me in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want the `Welcome.aspx` to require users to log in. If so, you can achieve that by adjusting page's [ACLs](https://docs.kentico.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=58335521) at `Page -> Edit -> Security` and setting the `Website logon page URL` at `Settings -> Security & Membership`.

You can either set the page to be accessible by certain roles or at least require authentication.
There is an example in Corporate sample site - in section Partners.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the recommended [Portal Engine](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Choosing+the+right+development+model) development model, you can set the permissions of the page on the Properties>Security tab.  There you'd add a role of not authenticated and set the property to deny.  Also ensure you have a default "login" page set in the settings.